# How do we configure SSL for flink opensearch connector

Tags: apache-flink, opensearch

Could you please guide me on how to configure SSL for pushing streaming data to an OpenSearch index using Apache Flink? I have referred to the official Flink documentation,

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/opensearch/

but I am encountering SSL exceptions, and I couldn't find an option to set SSL configurations.

below is stacktrace

org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Complete bulk has failed. at org.apache.flink.connector.opensearch.sink.OpensearchWriter$BulkListener.lambda$afterBulk$1(OpensearchWriter.java:302) ~[?:?] at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:50) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1] at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:90) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1] at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMail(MailboxProcessor.java:398) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1] at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMailsNonBlocking(MailboxProcessor.java:383) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1] at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMail(MailboxProcessor.java:345) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1] at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:229) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1] at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:839) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1] at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:788) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1] at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:952) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1] at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:931) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1] at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:745) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1] at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:562) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1] at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?] Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?] at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[?:?] at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[?:?] at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[?:?] at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(Unknown Source) ~[?:?] at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(Unknown Source) ~[?:?] at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown Source) ~[?:?] at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source) ~[?:?] at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?] at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]

The following code is used

```
`package cpm.dev.flinkApp.processor;
import com.dev.flinkApp.schema.OrderDetails;
import org.apache.flink.connector.opensearch.sink.OpensearchSinkBuilder;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.SingleOutputStreamOperator;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.opensearch.action.index.IndexRequest;
import org.opensearch.action.update.UpdateRequest;
import org.opensearch.client.Requests;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class OrderProcessor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<OrderDetails> stream = ....
        stream.sinkTo(
                new OpensearchSinkBuilder<OrderDetails>()
                        .setBulkFlushMaxActions(1)
                        .setHosts(new HttpHost("hostname1", 9200, "https"),
                                new HttpHost("hostname2", 9200, "https"))
                        .setConnectionUsername("OPEN_SEARCH_USERNAME")
                        .setConnectionPassword("OPEN_SEARCH_PASSWORD")
                        .setEmitter(
                                (element, context, indexer) ->
                                        indexer.add(createIndexRequest(element)))
                        .build());
        env.execute();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static IndexRequest createIndexRequest(OrderDetails element) {
        Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<>();
        json.put("orderNo", element.getOrderId());
        json.put("orderName", element.getProductName());
        json.put("orderDate", element.getOrderDate());
        json.put("orderBy", element.getOrderBy());
        return Requests.indexRequest().index("order-processing-detail-dev").id(element.getOrderId()).source(json);
    }
}`
```